# How to set Spring annotation value from environment variable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to set the value for `@Order` annotation in the following way:

```java
@Order(value = "#{environment.orderConfig}")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class LocalDevSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

In my environment file, I have the value of `orderConfig` as an integer.
The issue here is that `value` expects an `int` whereas `#{environment.orderConfig}` is a `String`. Is there any way to use the value stored in the environment variable?

Comment: No there isn't. The `@Order` doesn't support SpEL.

Comment: Okay, so in that case, is it possible to switch different WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter based on environment variables?

Comment: Use a conditionalOn.. .Apparently you want to load something based on profile Use an `@Profile` or else an `@ConditionalOnProperty` if you want properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Order` annotation does not support this.

Comment: is it possible to switch different WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter based on environment variables then?